# Unity 3d simulate touch on screen play mode test case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, unity-test-tools

I am writing playmode test case. I want to simulate touch/click at certain co-ordinate on screen for example (100,100)

So far I just found following code

```
Input.simulateMouseWithTouches = true;
```

Any idea how simulate touch at a point in unity playmode test case?

Comment: Injecting synthetic events into unity legacy Input System, or into its Event System is very tricky. To make it testable/simulatable, its useful to from an intemediate layer. Make your handing of the multi touch accept a reasonable parameter set, than you can call it both using the actual touch surface feedback, and your test code.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: hard to propose anything without seeing what you are trying to do with the touch events

Comment: Want to simulate normal touch anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You want one-touch, two-touch, multi-touch detection on the screen, don't you?
You can use **Input.GetTouch** to get touch information. To count the number of touch on the screen, you use **Input.touchCount** and **TouchPhase** to check the status of the touch.